# Grand sum of distinct values in xslt1.0

Tags: distinct, xslt-1.0

```
<customer>
  <item>
    <BILLNO>1</BILLNO>
    <product>ABC</product>
    <AMT>20</AMT>
  </item>
  <item>
    <BILLNO>2</BILLNO>
    <product>GHK</product>
    <AMT>30</AMT>
  </item>
  <item>
    <BILLNO>1</BILLNO>
    <product>XYZ</product>
    <AMT>20</AMT>
  </item>
</customer>
```

I am trying to take grand sum of distinct values using xslt1.0.
 I want the output like this using muenchian method.each bill will have multiple products. at the end of the day i need total number of bills and total amount

```
<sales>
  <totalbills>2</totalbills>
  <totalamount>50</totalamount>
</sales>
```

Thanks for help
ram

Answer (score 0):

This Xslt stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="item-key" match="item" use="BILLNO/text()"/>

  <xsl:template match="/customer">
    <root>
      <xsl:for-each select="item[generate-id() = generate-id(key('item-key', BILLNO/text()))]">
        <sales>
          <totalbills>
            <xsl:value-of select="count(../item[BILLNO = current()/BILLNO])"/>
          </totalbills>
          <totalamount>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(../item[BILLNO = current()/BILLNO]/AMT)"/>
          </totalamount>
        </sales>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

renders the following ouptut:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <sales>
    <totalbills>2</totalbills>
    <totalamount>40</totalamount>
  </sales>
  <sales>
    <totalbills>1</totalbills>
    <totalamount>30</totalamount>
  </sales>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This short and simpler transformation (no `xsl:for-each`, no `..`, no `text()` useage):**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kBills" match="item" use="BILLNO"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vdistItems" select=
  "/*/*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kBills', BILLNO)[1])]"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <sales>
      <totalbills><xsl:value-of select="count($vdistItems)"/></totalbills>
      <totalamount><xsl:value-of select="sum($vdistItems/AMT)"/></totalamount>
     </sales>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<customer>
  <item>
    <BILLNO>1</BILLNO>
    <product>ABC</product>
    <AMT>20</AMT>
  </item>
  <item>
    <BILLNO>2</BILLNO>
    <product>GHK</product>
    <AMT>30</AMT>
  </item>
  <item>
    <BILLNO>1</BILLNO>
    <product>XYZ</product>
    <AMT>20</AMT>
  </item>
</customer>
```

**produces the exact wanted, correct result:**

```
<sales>
   <totalbills>2</totalbills>
   <totalamount>50</totalamount>
</sales>
```

**Explanation**: Appropriate use of

1. **The [Muenchian method for grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)**.
2. **The [`sum()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-sum) function**.